# realpath api and shell realpath command have not the same result

Tags: android, linux, shell

I calling realpath("/sdcard") api in android and got "/storage/emulated/legacy" but when check result in shell

> root@vbox86p:/ # ls -l /storage/emulated
>
> lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2017-11-08 05:25 legacy -> /mnt/shell/emulated/0

i have a link, not a real path to mounted sdcard folder

next i try to check the same in shell

> root@vbox86p:/ # realpath /sdcard
>
> /mnt/shell/emulated/0

i try to search in android sources how did realpath command works, but can't find it.
So i have a question - why did realpath api returning not real path? How i can receive real path to mounted sdcard folder?

i working on genymotion android 5.0

Comment: Try ls -l /storage

Comment: 1|root@vbox86p:/ # ls -l /storage
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2017-11-08 05:25 emulated
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2017-11-08 05:25 sdcard0 -> /storage/emulated/legacy

and what its mean, can you explain. please.
i'm littlebit newbie in linux.

Comment: You should use also a file explorer app on your emulator. Then find out the path to the sd card. Then tell us.

Comment: i have installed RootFileExplorer, tap on "SDCARD" and see path "/sdcard". When click on "STORAGE" i get "/storage/emulated/0" and the same file list as in /sdcard path.
additionally i have output from "mount" command in shell:
/dev/fuse /mnt/shell/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permssions,allow_other 0 0
now ls -l /mnt/shell/emulated
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_r          2017-11-08 07:01 0
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_r          2017-07-24 12:00 legacy

and folder with name "0" is the sdcard root directory.

Comment: /sdcard is not the path to an SD card. Nor is /storage/emulated/0. You should look again until you find the real path.